# Could not resolve dependencies for project, except when called with package

Tags: maven

I have an EAR project, defined very similarly as [the reference project of WildFly](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/kitchensink-ear). In addition to that, I have another JAR project `JarProject`
which is included in:

- parent's pom.xml (as a `<module>` and in its `<dependencyManagement>`)
- the `EjbProject`'s pom.xml (with the scope provided)
- the `EarProject`'s pom.xml (with the default scope, `compile`)

The problem is that when executing `mvn eclipse:eclipse` or `mvn wildfly:deploy` (from the parent project) it fails with the error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project EjbProject: Could not resolve dependencies for project groupId:EjbProject:jar:0.0.4-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact groupId:JarProject:jar:0.0.4-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

It somehow looks the JarProject in the local repository, and does not see it in the parent project.

*Very important note:* `mvn package` works without problems, as `mvn package wildfly:deploy` or `mvn package eclipse:eclipse` do, but without `pacakge`ing before `eclipse:eclipse`, it fails.

Maven version: 3.0.4 and 3.3.3

Comment: Is the JarProject installed in your local repository? Maven goal "package" build the jar. Goal "install" install it in your local repository.

Comment: No, the JarProject is not there, as nobody installed it in the local repository.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got the question. Hope this will help...

Goals "eclipse:eclipse" and "wildfly:deploy" do not trigger building of your projects. To use a project as a dependency it needs to be built from the parent pom or installed in you repository.
When you do `mvn package eclipse:eclipse` the `package` triggers the build of the JarProject.

If you want do be able to do only `mvn eclipse:eclipse` then you need to perform a `mvn install` on your JarProject first.

Comment: This solved a similar problem using the protobuf-maven-plugin:compile-python.

Running mvn -am install first allowed it to build the python files properly.